# What is the Selenium 3 equivalent of getting an OK message to test the server is up?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using BASH scripts to check if Selenium is up and running before continuing with a test.

In the past for Selenium 2 I have used the below command to test if the server is up or not.

```
http://<<selenium_pc>>:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=getLogMessages
```

This returns back "OK,". I use curl and store the value returned back in a variable and then just compare to see if should continue the test.

When I moved to Selenium 3 I haven't been able to find this equivalent command. What I am doing in the meantime is to use curl to get the page back and store it in a variable and then compare that against a file I saved locally and catted in to another variable for comparison.

This isn't as elegant.

I could use:

```
http://<<selenium_pc>>:4444/wd/hub/status
```

But this gives me a JSON object back that has a hCode value that always changes.

Am I missing anything obvious?

Adam

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke the [URL](http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status)

it gives you back this JSON

```
{
    "state": "success",
    "sessionId": null,
    "hCode": 1508265052,
    "value": {
        "build": {
            "version": "3.0.1",
            "revision": "1969d75",
            "time": "2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700"
        },
        "os": {
            "name": "Mac OS X",
            "arch": "x86_64",
            "version": "10.12.1"
        },
        "java": {
            "version": "1.8.0_66"
        }
    },
    "class": "org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response",
    "status": 0
}
```

You should be able to easily just parse this JSON object which you get as a response and work with that no ? For e.g., from the above response you could easily parse the value of `state` (or) the value of `status` using techniques described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955555/679824).